# multiple links in if statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement, hyperlink

I have a script that specifices that a certain element does not be shown when on a specific page. Below is the code I used:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
   function callOnPageLoad()
   {
   var url = window.location.href;
   if(url == "http://www.exampledomain.com")
   {
   document.getElementById('rolex').style.display = 'none';
   }
   }
   </script>
```

However I need to put a few more url's in the if statement, what is the right way of doing this?

Many thanks

Comment: [Top 10 Best JavaScript Books that Beginners should Read](http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2010/03/top-10-best-javascript-books-that-beginners-should-read.html)

Comment: A lot of potential problems with that code Hugh, try capitalising some of it in the address bar, remove the www, disable JS, etc etc.

Answer (score 2):

I preffer to generate associative array and then check if string is set. It can be obtained from AJAX, from different script etc. and isn't hradcoded into if

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
   var urlArray = { "http://www.exampledomain.com" : true, "http://www.exampledomain.com/foobar.html" : true };
   function callOnPageLoad()
   {
   var url = window.location.href;
   if( urlArray[url] )
   {
   document.getElementById('rolex').style.display = 'none';
   }
   }
   </script>
```

Comment: Note that objects have a bunch of properties by default so "URLs" like `toString` or `eval` will also be accepted. To prevent this use `if (urlArray.hasOwnProperty(url))` instead of `if (urlArray[url])`.

Comment: +1 for this, i think this might be quicker than the other suggestions (multiple ors, in operator, for loop). Of course the difference in performance doesn't make an issue, but...

Answer (score 0):

```
if(url == "http://www.exampledomain.com" || url == "http://www.anotherdomain.com")
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add more conditions in the if block:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
   function callOnPageLoad()
   {
   var url = window.location.href;
   if(url == "http://www.exampledomain.com" || url == "anotherurl" || url == "andanother")
   {
   document.getElementById('rolex').style.display = 'none';
   }
   }
   </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

have an array of urls and iterate

```
function callOnPageLoad()
{
   var urls = [
      "http://www.exampledomain.com",
      "http://www.exampledomain2.com"
   ];
   var url = window.location.href;
   for ( var i=0; i < urls.length; i++ ) {
      if(url == urls[i])
      {
          document.getElementById('rolex').style.display = 'none';
          break;
      }
   }   

}
```

Comment: i think better to use "in"  operator than use loop

Comment: Do you have some benchmarks that "in" is faster than than a for loop?

Answer (score 0):

you can create an array of those urls and run for loop thought them, this will be more dynamic approach to your problem.

using long if statements is not advisible because you can loose a character here or a bit of logic there

If your urls point to external urls or match other patterns that you can distinguish them from other urls you can use it without an array.

Answer (score 0):

```
 function callOnPageLoad(type)

    {
        var url = window.location.href;
             var urls=new array("http://www.exampledomain1com","http://www.exampledomain2.com");    


        if(url in urls){
            document.getElementById('rolex').style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
```

Comment: Show me a place where it works then? This doesn't: http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/nTyms/

Answer (score 0):

`if(url == "http://www.exampledomain.com" || url =="http://www.url2.com" || url == "http://www.url3.com")` and so forth ... ?